# Can src of a image be set from a client's resources?

Tags: html, image, localhost

I am trying to get a web page working the following way.
Can someone throw light if this is possible?

There is an  in the page whose src needs to be set dynamically.
Can this src be taken from the client's PC running the browser? (eg. c:\Images)
I want to use the local system's resources and also want to remove the need to upload the file

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, this is only possible if the html file embedding the image is on the client's computer too.

On the other hand: Why would you know, that the Image under C:... exists on the client's computer?